# Cant seem to get this query to work

Tags: php, sql

This query was working on mij older login script, But now that i have this new login script, my code had to change a litlle, Wich i cant seem to pull off. Im think the troubles are in the end where the if user is online is checked...

This is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('index.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php
    function pay_credits() {
    mysqli_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `credits`=`credits`-'1' WHERE `watching`='1' AND `credits`>'0' AND userID=:uid");
    } 
?>

<?php
    pay_credits();
?>
```

The top script is working fine, But the function pay_credits doesnt work, Ive tried changing mysql to mysqli as i hear alot over that it has deprecated and stuff, But still no result, Ive also been reading about pdo but i have no knowledge of this. Any help is welcome, I also like to learn so maybe you can explain what you`ve done a litlle.   Thnx :)

Comment: these scripts cant be copy pasted, they need to be a custom fit, how on earth can you then have a duplicated lol...

Answer (score 0):

**First**: if you read [mysqli_query manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you'll see that `mysqli_query` takes two arguments. First is `link` and second is a `query string`.

Do you see a `link` in your `pay_credits` function? Nope.

**Second**: I noticed that you use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and then suddenly switch to `mysqli`.

`PDO` and `mysqli` are **totally different APIs** and you should choose which one you use.

Comment: so what direction do i need to look, pdo that performs a query, or create a new mysqli with new database connection that injects my function?

Answer (score 0):

You use `pay_credits()` without settings, your function `mysqli_query` need a params for db connection.

Comment: Ive also tried to include my config.php, So i therefor think msqli_query does have the params for the database connection, yet it still wont update ?   And pay_credits doesnt need settings, its been included and excluded by another function, when its included it needs to stay running.

Comment: What param im i missing here then, it is saying i have 1 of the 2 required... Pls i am not as advanced as you guys.